# Wrong Day Of Week from java time api

Tags: java, datetime, time

I am using java 8 time API to convert time in milliseconds to date and I am getting wrong day of week from that date.
here is my code -

```
long millis = 1406865600000L; 
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(millis/1000);
DayOfWeek dow = localDate.getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(dow);
```

it prints out THURSDAY, while this is date Friday 1 AUG.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

[`LocalDate.ofEpochDay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-) expects *day count* as its argument, and you're passing *second count* (which is what you get when dividing millisecond count by 1000).

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25663122/642706) is correct.

## Solution code example

Here is code to handle the situation correctly.

If your input number is a number of milliseconds since the epoch of start of 1970 in UTC, then create an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1406865600000L );
```

Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still being “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

So adjust your `Instant` into a `ZonedDateTime` object by applying your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Ask for the day-of-week. Java represents each of the seven days of the week in the enum [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek();
```

Ask the `DayOfWeek` object to translate the name of the day of the week to a human language defined in a `Locale`.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Dump to console. Results, at least for `America/Montreal`, are as you expect, Friday 1 AUG.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | dow: " + dow + " | output: " + output );
```

> input: 1406865600000 | instant: 2014-08-01T04:00:00Z | zdt: 2014-08-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal] | dow: FRIDAY | output: vendredi